# How can I sum specific values of dicts while reducing a list of dicts?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dicts with the following structure:

```
  {
    "acquirer_id": 1,
    "acquirer_name": "CIELO",
    "client_id": 15520,
    "created_at": "2020-09-03T17:39:52.233566",
    "fee_amount": 0, # Needs to be added
    "net_amount": 0, # Needs to be added
    "quantity": 0, # Needs to be added
    "sales_amount": 0, # Needs to be added
    "sales_average": 0, # Needs to be added
    "sales_date": "2020-08-13"
  }
```

I've seen [Sum list of dictionaries with same key](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sum-list-of-dictionaries-with-same-key/), but the problem is that I don't have only ints. I've tried to separate the dicts filtering strings and numbers like:

```
separated_dicts = [({key: value for (key, value) in _dict.items() if isinstance(value, str)}, {
                     key: value for (key, value) in _dict.items() if isinstance(value, numbers.Number)}) for _dict in sales]
```

In order to sum just the one with the numbers and merge later, but then, I can't sum the `acquirer_id` and `client_id` **because they're ids**. So, I have to reduce the list of dicts to a single dict, adding specific values of each dict. What's the most pythonic way of doing so?

Comment: How about the `client_id`? Shouldn't it be excluded as well since it's an id too?

Comment: Yes, I've mentioned just the acquirer_id as an example

Comment: Yes, it needs to be an instance of numbers.Number because there are some floats there too.

Comment: Try `sum(v for k, v in d.items() if (not "id" in k) and  isinstance(v, (int, float)))`?

Comment: Do you want to sum all the numbers in each dict or do you want to end up with another dictionary where all the keys contain the sum of those keys from all the other dictionaries?

Comment: What items should the resulting dictionary have for those that _aren't_ being summed?

Comment: I've edited the question showing which keys should be added. It's a list with N dicts in that structure, I need to reduce all of them to a single dict with the marked values added from all dicts. I can't find a way to do this reduce function.

Comment: You edit didn't answer my question…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a new list of dicts with only the keys that need to be summed:

```
from numbers import Number
summable_sales = [
    {k: v for k, v in d.items() if isinstance(v, Number) and not k.endswith("_id")}
    for d in sales
]
```

then [sum all the dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50782754):

```
from collections import Counter
sums = Counter()
for d in summable_sales:
    sums.update(d)
print(d)
```

Answer (score -1):

I've used two equal entries in a list just for example. Non-id fields with type `int` or `float` are summed and the rest of fields are agreggated in a list, if you need just last value of those fields append `[-1]` to the end of `[e.get(k, None) for e in l]` to take the last element.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBBb8IwDIXv@RVWL6RSQaVZ2ai007TDpGm77IYQCtRlEWkKjYtAiN/epdAWmE/J5/fsJ2@P9FsYUdcHeIUTA1eeXO0qVWK5UKmXwDj4R43M0XHv7eP989truyut0FDriOMo7HiJkjBdSGosURiFw3A6DMXP@DkR0ySORpEQ8WTSzckQFzIvKkN3qw3SDUYt3FXSkKKjQ6JFVmq0N@XTI95jKddN8viBpy7fLdvLcCw8dmZMu3vMDgEc5oxtS2WIX6@zgQT45dWUrXKOozUS3wQQ@pAVJSAoA9rvNSoDZW21XGlpLacAuJsWQKYLSb4P0qQwcIcbgCmosW4AtcXePuvnfxUG71fML5orce2L@dT7mqB03CLf33s68b754UgR5pZfs57739lndf0H)

```
x = {
    "acquirer_id": 1,
    "acquirer_name": "CIELO",
    "client_id": 15520,
    "created_at": "2020-09-03T17:39:52.233566",
    "fee_amount": 1,
    "net_amount": 2,
    "quantity": 3,
    "sales_amount": 4,
    "sales_average": 5,
    "sales_date": "2020-08-13"
}

l = [x, x]

print({
    k : (
        sum(e.get(k, 0) for e in l)
        if issubclass(t, (int, float)) and '_id' not in k else
        [e.get(k, None) for e in l]
    ) for k, t in {
        k : type(v) for e in l for k, v in e.items()
    }.items()
})
```

Output:

```
{
    "acquirer_id": [1, 1],
    "acquirer_name": ["CIELO", "CIELO"],
    "client_id": [15520, 15520],
    "created_at": ["2020-09-03T17:39:52.233566", "2020-09-03T17:39:52.233566"],
    "fee_amount": 2,
    "net_amount": 4,
    "quantity": 6,
    "sales_amount": 8,
    "sales_average": 10,
    "sales_date": ["2020-08-13", "2020-08-13"],
}
```